# CSS menu hover not working

Tags: css

I want to build a menu where every single `<li>` hovers out. But weirdly the whole menu always hovers out. Here is the [fiddle code.](http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippB/X96KE/)

**I have the following css code:**

```
body {
background-color: #eee;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

.tabs {
    width: 80%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 100px;
}
.tabs ul {
    display:block;
}
.tabs li {
    width: 60px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    font-family: verdana;
    text-align: center;
}
.tabs li:hover {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is that when you give **margin** to it then it's push whole `ul`. It's better give `bottom` instead of `margin`. write like this:

```
.tabs li:hover {
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/X96KE/17/

Answer (score 2):

using jQuery will solve your problem if you are familiar with it try this

```
  jQuery("li").mouseover(function() {
    jQuery(this).css("margin-bottom","20px");
  }).mouseout(function(){
   jQuery(this).css("margin-bottom","0px");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't specified what to do with the margin-top.  Here's an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/X96KE/18/

```
.tabs li:hover {
    margin-bottom: -40px; 
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```